# The number of $7×7$ matrices with specific conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

I am asked to find the number of  $7×7$ matrices with entries $0,1,2,...,9$ whose determinant is not a multiple of $10$.

Expanding the determinant along rows (or columns) gives us a messy expression and, henceforth difficult to deal with.

Is it attackable using recurrences or we have to choose another approach? Please help me and give a hint to start with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to get an idea [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields).

Comment: The results in the linked page of wikipedia are for fileds $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ( p is a prime). Can we generalize this results to fileds of order $pq$ ?

Comment: I didn't mean it to be a ready-to-use answer. But OK, see mine below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M_n(m)$ be the set of *all* $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and let
$$Z_n(m)=\{A\in M_n(m) : \det A=0\}.$$
Chinese remainder theorem says that, for $m_1,m_2$ coprime, the map
$$A\mapsto(A\bmod m_1,A\bmod m_2)$$
is a bijection between $M_n(m_1 m_2)$ and $M_n(m_1)\times M_n(m_2)$, and also between $Z_n(m_1 m_2)$ and $Z_n(m_1)\times Z_n(m_2)$. From the link given in the comment above, for prime $p$ we have
$$F(n,p):=\#(M_n(p)\setminus Z_n(p))=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^k).$$
Thus the answer is $(pq)^{n^2}-\big(p^{n^2}-F(n,p)\big)\big(q^{n^2}-F(n,q)\big)$ for $n=7, p=2, q=5$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. +1